# Does googles .NET client Library support subscriptions and payments verification?

Tags: .net, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I noticed that google have `Google Play Developer API` section in .net API list (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/), but it references to `android publisher`. Does it have .NET API connector for `android developer API` features like purchases and subscriptions verification (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the package `https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3` able to work with subscriptions and payments

`PurchasesResource` class properties `Products` and `Subscriptions` should be used.
Here are the docs: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

The google .net client library is generated from the discovery services api.  Any api supported in that list  https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis.  I cant tell you how that page is generated it may or may not be up to date.

Should be found as a nuget package.

[image]

It appears to support three different versions of the android publisher api

The nuget package does exist

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3

If the API supports it it should be working in the package as again its generated from the discovery doc for the api itself.